# serializing objects in php to use in sessions

Tags: php, session, serialization

I am trying to serialize my object "ShoppingCart.php", and the object "Item.php", but i cant, and i dont know what else to do, so i leave here my code just to see if someone could help me. My problem is that the object ShoppingCart.php has a property which stores an array of Items, and i am not really sure if i am serializing/unserializing really well the object.

I have summarized my classes so they dont include all the methods, but they still show the most representatives. If still is not clear enought i will change it again.

Thanks in advance:

```
<?php 

class ShoppingCart implements Iterator, Countable,Serializable {

    // Array stores the list of items in the cart:
    protected $items = array();

    // For tracking iterations:
    protected $position = 0;

    // For storing the IDs, as a convenience:
    protected $ids = array();

    // Constructor just sets the object up for usage:
    function __construct() {
        $this->items = array();
        $this->ids = array();
    }


    // Adds a new item to the cart:
    public function addItem(Item $item) {

        // Need the item id:
        $id = $item->getId();

        // Throw an exception if there's no id:
        if (!$id) throw new Exception('The cart requires items with unique ID values.');

        // Add or update:
        if (isset($this->items[$id])) {
            $this->updateItem($item, $this->items[$id]['qty'] + 1);
        } else {
            $this->items[$id] = array('item' => $item, 'qty' => 1);
            $this->ids[] = $id; // Store the id, too!
        }

    } // End of addItem() method.

    // Changes an item already in the cart:
    public function updateItem(Item $item, $qty) {

        // Need the unique item id:
        $id = $item->getId();

        // Delete or update accordingly:
        if ($qty === 0) {
            $this->deleteItem($item);
        } elseif ( ($qty > 0) && ($qty != $this->items[$id]['qty'])) {
            $this->items[$id]['qty'] = $qty;
        }

    } // End of updateItem() method.

    // Removes an item from the cart:
    public function deleteItem(Item $item) {

        // Need the unique item id:
        $id = $item->getId();

        // Remove it:
        if (isset($this->items[$id])) {
            unset($this->items[$id]);

            // Remove the stored id, too:
            $index = array_search($id, $this->ids);
            unset($this->ids[$index]);

            // Recreate that array to prevent holes:
            $this->ids = array_values($this->ids);

        }

    } // End of deleteItem() method.



    public function serialize(){

        foreach ($this->items as $clave => $item)
            $listaItems[$clave]=serialize($this->items['item'][$clave]);

        foreach ($this-items as $clave=>$valor)
            $listaCantidades[$clave]=$this->items['qty'][$clave];

        return 
            array(
                'items'=>$listaItems,
                'qty'=>$listaCantidades,
                'ids'=>$this->ids,
                );

    }

    public function unserialize($data){
        //$data=unserialize($data);

        $this->items=array(
            'items'=>$data['items'],
            'qty'=>$data['qty']
            );
        $this->ids=$data['ids'];

        foreach($this->items as $clave => $item)
            $this->items[$clave]=unserialize($item);
    }

} // End of ShoppingCart class.


<?php # Item.php

// This is a sample Item class. 
// This class could be extended by individual applications.
class Item implements Serializable{

    // Item attributes are all protected:
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $description;

    public function serialize(){
        return serialize(
            array(
                'id'=>$this->id,
                'name'=>$this->name,
                'price'=>$this->price,              
                'description'=>$this->description           
            )

        );
    }

    public function unserialize($data){
        $data=unserialize($data);

        $this->id=$data['id'];
        $this->name=$data['name'];
        $this->price=$data['price'];
        $this->description=$data['description'];    
    }

    // Constructor populates the attributes:
    public function __construct($id, $name, $price) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    // Method that returns the ID:
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // Method that returns the name:
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    // Method that returns the price:
    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($descripcion){
        $this->description=$descripcion;
    }

} // End of Item class.
```

Comment: You should remove all unnecessary code and describe what your problem exactly is. If you do just want a code review, go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok thank you for your advice, i just have edited, but i still include some methods because i am interested that you can see how the array works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that objects implementing `Serializable` must return a *serialised* string from the `serialise` method. Currently you're returning an array of data. You should be doing this instead:

```
public function serialize() {
    ...

    return serialize(array(...));
}
```

You're actually doing this correctly in your `Item` class. However, I don't see why you're manually serialising in the first place. You're basically replicating the default behaviour of what `serialize()` already does without any added benefits. Just get rid of the `Serializable` interface and its implementation and the default behaviour of PHP's serialisation should serve you just fine. E.g.:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = $myShoppingCart;
```

Done. No implementation of `serialize` necessary in your case.

Comment: No, still not working, maybe i am wrong, but i know you serialize and unserialize an object for persistent of data. My problem is that the shopping cart use an array of objects so i dont know how to serialize it.

Comment: Again, I'm not really sure why you need to do anything special at all. See http://3v4l.org/VtXgD, it works without any special code.

Comment: It is ok, i think my problem was that i was reading the array wrong and i was thinking that the object didnt serialized correctly. Thank you for your help